# How can I clear unnecessary files in .metadata folder?

Tags: android

I know the .metadata folder saved some settings of the eclipse's project workspace, but the size and files of the folder keep increase.
How can I clear unnecessary files in  .metadata folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a massive workspace? Try Project->Clean...->Clean All

Comment: Thanks!, but I find the size of the folder .metadata  is the same after I run  Project->Clean...->Clean All.